# Searching Unique Id in Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

I have a Scenario where i am required to search unique id in Mutiple tables and assign a level based on where it exist.

```
Table Hierarchy

        TableA
                TableB
                         TableC
```

Table B holds primary key of table A and Table C holds the Primary of TableB

I need to have a function that takes Id as parameter and Searches that Id in this Table Hierarchy and Return Level i-e If it exist in TableA Level should be One. If it exists in TableB Level should be 2 and if it's in TableC then level should be 3

Comment: What if it exists in more than one table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableC WHERE id = @id) THEN '3'
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE id = @id) THEN '2'
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE id = @id) THEN 'One'
       END AS "Level"
```

Comment: How this can be transformed into a function that takes Id as parameter and Returns Level for each row. Basically i want to use it in Query

Answer (score 0):

You need a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE id = {0}
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM TableB WHERE id = {0}
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM TableC WHERE id = {0}
```

The advantage to this over "WHEN" statements is that a) I don't like WHEN statements, and b) if a key exists in multiple tables, this returns a record for each, giving you the opportunity to build program logic around handling that case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return the highest level, 3 being the highest for TableC, then something like this should work using the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN C.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 3 
     WHEN B.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
     WHEN A.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
   END as Level 
FROM (SELECT @Id as Id) H
   LEFT JOIN TableA A ON H.Id = A.Id
   LEFT JOIN TableB B ON H.Id = B.Id
   LEFT JOIN TableC C ON H.Id = C.Id
```

Where @Id is the Id of the value you are searching for, for example SELECT 1 as Id.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, there is no table as Hierarchy. There are three tables i-e TaBLEA, TABLEB and TABLEC